# Anything that stands out why this would break in firefox like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Anything that stand out why this would break in firefox like this:

```
var test = ko.dataFor($(event.target).closest('blah')[0]);
```

The error message is:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined.

Doesn't happen for IE or Chrome.

Comment: Firefox doesn't have a global event object, IE and Chrome does. It's not clear from the posted code where the event would originate from, i.e. there's no event handler here, so noone can help you unless you post more code

Comment: well that answers my question, so if you want to put that as the answer below I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE originally had a global event object, meaning it would be available without naming the argument

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(event); // would be the object in IE
});
```

All though this is not really standard behaviour, Chrome decided to implement this as well.

In Firefox however, `event` would be undefined in the above code, and the argument would have to named, as in

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event); // works everywhere, ^ becase it's there
});
```

This is how it should be done, without relying on the global event object

Comment: Thanks for the insight as well, i'll mark it in 7 minutes!